# Publish Joint_State with Python to RVIZ

Tags: ros, python, rviz, publish, joint-state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot that I built in URDF that I am visualizing in RVIZ. I can control the joints using the gui tool or a rostopic pub command, but I am unable to build a publisher node to interface with the rviz visualization.

The rostopic pub works fine so I tried to build a ros package that would publish the joint information to the rviz visualization. "Rostopic echo /joint_states" lists the newly published command, but the rviz model does not move.

I am able to use the following command to move the robot using a terminal:

```
rostopic pub -1 /joint_states sensor_msgs/JointState '{header: auto, name: ['joint0', 'joint1', 'joint2', 'joint3'], position: [1, 0.5418, -1.7297, -3.1017], velocity: [], effort: []}'
```

Here is the code I am trying to build to publish the same information. I built it into a package that I am running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from std_msgs.msg import Header

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('joint_state_publisher')
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    hello_str = JointState()
    hello_str.header = Header()
    hello_str.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    hello_str.name = ['joint0', 'joint1', 'joint2', 'joint3']
    hello_str.position = [3, 0.5418, -1.7297, -3.1017]
    hello_str.velocity = []
    hello_str.effort = []
    pub.publish(hello_str)
    rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

After I run the package to move the robot, rostopic list shows  the new state, but the robot has not moved in RVIZ.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213075/publish-joint_state-with-python-to-rviz/) by [kevlarkevlar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23084/kevlarkevlar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-07-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-08**:\

> I can control the joints using the gui tool [..]

Which tool are you referring to here? `rqt_publisher`, `joint_state_publisher` or something else?

**Comment by [umar_anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/82934/umar_anjum/) on 2022-01-27**:
he is referring to joint_state_publisher_gui, http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher_gui

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-28**:
That package didn't exist in 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> def talker():
> ```

```
    pub = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('joint_state_publisher')
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    hello_str = JointState()
    [..]
    pub.publish(hello_str)
    rate.sleep()
```

What do expect this does? You have no loop construct in there, and the `rate` is set to sleep for 0.1 seconds only. I can imagine that is not enough time for ROS to be able to successfully distribute your message to the rest of the system (especially not the *first message*). The `talker()` function will exit (and take all things in its scope with it) after a very short time.

Even for testing (so with static data), I'd recommend something like:

```
def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('joint_states', JointState, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('joint_state_publisher')
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    hello_str = JointState()
    [..]

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      hello_str.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
      pub.publish(hello_str)
      rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kevlarkevlar](https://answers.ros.org/users/23084/kevlarkevlar/) on 2015-07-08**:
Thanks, that worked! I had never worked with static data publishing.